# Is $R = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ a reflexive relation on $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations

Suppose I have a set $\mathrm{A}=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and a reflexive relation $\mathrm R$ defined on $\mathrm A$, i.e.,

$$R\colon A\mapsto A\quad\textrm{and}\quad \mathrm R\textrm{ is reflexive.}$$

Is the relation quoted below a possible candidate for being $\mathrm{R}$ ?

> $$\mathrm R=\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$$

**My reasoning:**

Since the definition of a reflexive relation $\mathrm R$ on $\mathrm A$ is that $a\mathrm Ra~\forall~a\in\mathrm A$, we have that the given relation is not reflexive on $\mathrm{A}$ and hence not a possible candidate for being $\mathrm R$. The main fact used here is that $3,4,5\in\mathrm A$ but $\require{cancel} a\cancel {\mathrm R} a$ for $a=3,4,5$

Comment: I agree with your reasoning.

Comment: By the way, "$R:A\mapsto A$" is not really standard notation for "$R$ is a binary relation on $A$". It would be clearer to write just $R\subseteq A\times A$.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct, and there's nothing really further to comment on. $R$ would be reflexive if and only if $(a,a) \in R$ for every $a \in A$; however, since that doesn't hold for $a=3,4,5$, $R$ is not a reflexive relation on $A$.

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*